# Some simple questions about confusion matrix and metrics in general

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, class-imbalance, metric, confusion-matrix

I will first tell you about the context then ask my questions.

The model detects hate speech and the training and testing datasets are imbalanced (NLP).

My questions:

1. Is this considered a good model?
2. Is the False negative really bad and it indicates that my model will predict a lot of ones to be zeros on new data?
3. Is it common for AUC to be higher than the recall and precision when the data is imbalanced?
4. Is the ROC-AUC misleading in this case because it depends on the True Negative and it is really big? (FPR depends on TN)
5. For my use case, what is the best metric to use?
6. I passed the probabilities to create ROC, is that the right way?

[image]

**Edit:
I did under-sampling and got the following results from the same model parameters:**
[image]

**Does this show that the model is good? or can it be misleading too?**

Comment: What are your class ratios?

Comment: @liakoyras 14k to 2k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first model where the `f1_score` is around 61% can not be considered as a good model. You can achieve much better results than that. This can be seen in the second case (where you have downsampled the dataset), where the `f1_score` increases substantially.

Since your problem statement is to detect hate speech, you would have to decrease both, the FP and the FN or in other words, increase the `precision` and `recall`.

I would the say the metric in this case would be the `f1_score` which is a combination of `precision` and `recall`.

Also instead of downsampling, try oversampling. Or better yet, do neither and instead use other techniques to counteract the imbalance (think cross validation particulary `RepeatedStratifiedCV`, or maybe get more data for the minority class not by oversampling but from the authentic sources. )

Comment: I will try to find more hate speech data, but I have a question: Is it a good practice to under sample? Is the sample still representative? Should I always try to make my data balanced even if it means to down sample?

Comment: When you oversample or downsample your data, the resulting sample will not be representative of the real dataset, since the real dataset is imbalanced and by downsampling your are balancing the dataset. Whether it is a good practice is a subjective matter. The best thing to do is try to get authentic data in increase the minority class as this would balance your dataset as well as not introduce any noise (which in the case of down or over sampling, you are basically introducing noise, albeit intelligent noise).

Answer (score 3):

Most of your questions cannot be objectively answered.

Whether or not a model is good depends on what is the use for it.

Seeing how your classes are imbalanced, it definitely affects the metrics you presented. Do *you* care more about False Positives or False Negatives? What are the consequences of this? How many False Negatives are you willing to allow in order to have less False Positives?

> Is it common for AUC to be higher than the recall and precision when the data is imbalanced?

This is an example of your model not being "as good" (given the caveats I mentioned). High ROC AUC means that your data can be ranked well while varying the threshold, which is to be expected since most of your data belongs in one class. But when considering precision-recall as individual metrics, at least one of those (precision if you have a lot of FP and recall if you have a lot of FN) will be more sensitive to the type of error you have, thus having lower values.

> For my use case, what is the best metric to use?

F1 score is a pretty solid option whenever there are imbalanced classes, because as I mentioned it punishes both FP and FN.

But, by its definition, it is an average (harmonic mean) between precision and recall. If you care more about reducing a specific type of error, you can focus more on maximizing the more specific metrics (precision/recall).

> I passed the probabilities to create ROC, is that the right way?

Yes it is. ROC is dependent on classification threshold, thus it needs to know the probability in order to be able to determine where to classify the sample given the specific threshold it checks each time.

Comment: Thank you for the very good answer. Do the results I got after under-sampling mean that the model will perform good or is the sample not representative anymore?

Comment: I think it means that your model performs better on balanced datasets, which is to be expected. Training on imbalanced datasets has its benefites (for example reducing FPR) and in a lot of cases it is the only possible way due to lack of data, but it has the side effect that the model is heavily biased towards the majority class. For example if your model was always predicting Negative, in your 14:2 scenario it would be correct 6/7 times (86% accuracy), making it only slightly worse than the original model. That's why it is important to consider which is more important, FP or FN.